# Can't properly measure custom view?

Tags: android, custom-controls

I'm writing a custom `View` object, but I can't seem to get it to measure correctly. By looking at the [`View` source code](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/View.java), I thought calling `setMinimumHeight()` and `setMinimumWidth()` would be enough (that's really all I need, a minimum size that the parent layout should respect). Here's my code:

```
public class MonthView extends View {

    private final int minCellSize = 24;

    public MonthView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MonthView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MonthView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        setMinimumHeight((int) (minCellSize * scale * 6));
        setMinimumWidth((int) (minCellSize * scale * 7));
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Pretty simple. I then embed it in a `LinearLayout`, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <com.foghina.adtp.MonthView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="I am below the monthview!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, the `MonthView` takes up the entire screen and the `TextView` is not visible. How can I correctly write my `View` so that it has a minimum height / width when `wrap_content` is used?

Comment: why is the layout_height and weight of the text view set like this? remove weight and set height to wrap_content? what does happen?

Comment: @Sherif nothing. Also, the `height="0dp" weight="1"` technique is recommended on Android, as the view doesn't need to be measured (it just takes up any remaining space in the parent layout). If you run the `layoutopt` tool it will suggest that you use a `0dp` height of width in many places :)

Comment: in onMeasure() you should use `setMeasuredDimension`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out eventually. I had to write my own version of `View.getDefaultSize()` that is just slightly different. Here's how I used it:

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    setMeasuredDimension(getSize((int) (minCellSize * scale * 7), widthMeasureSpec),
            getSize((int) (minCellSize * scale * 6), heightMeasureSpec));
}

private static int getSize(int size, int measureSpec) {
    int result = size;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize =  MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    switch (specMode) {
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        result = size;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
        result = size < specSize ? size : specSize;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        result = specSize;
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Pretty nasty. I don't understand why the default `View.getDefaultSize()` doesn't work like that.

Comment: For economy of code lines, the static method `resolveSize(size,spec)` does exactly what your `getSize()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use [setMeasureDimension()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMeasuredDimension%28int,%20int%29)